# Acidentally used gzip -r and now individual files in many sublevels are zipped

Tags: command-line

I tried to use the gzip command on my public_html folder, and I've landed in a pretty big mess.

Exact command I used: `gzip -r /home/account/www/`

Now, in many sub-levels I have individually compressed .gz files. Is there an easy way to undo my actions?

Comment: Is the directory structure still the same, just files gzipped?

Comment: Yes, as far as i can tell

Comment: I've seen this and attempted, but haven't been able to work it out. Simply retunrs `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header`

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the `find` command with `gunzip` like so:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.gz' -exec gunzip "{}" \;
```

Make sure you do this from the /home/account/www directory, or use this command

```
find /home/account/www -type f -iname '*.gz' -exec gunzip "{}" \;
```

Comment: returns `find: paths must precede expression: loopTest.php.gz`

Comment: Did you miss the `.` ?

Comment: Copied your command fully, and i was in the directory. Either way, hadn't noticed the second answer in @kos 's link, which solved my issue. Thank you anyway.

Comment: OFFTOPIC: This community seems much better than the remaning stackexhance I've met.

Comment: Thanks @kos, I was wondering about using `{} +`. Thought this would be closed as a dupe though.